# Brew postinstall mysql@5.7 complaining about data directory not empty when it is empty

Tags: homebrew, mysql-5.7

Having a lot of trouble installing mysql 5.7 on Mac Mojave, (ran 'brew install mysql@5.7')

on initial install, got msg saying postinstall was not completed successfully (please see msg below).

So, after I delete everything in the directory /usr/local/var/mysql (which mysql says is not empty), I STILL get same message when re-running postinstall command ... (which is quite annoying seems MySQL is populating the data dir then complaining it is not empty?!)

```
[08:02:48][~/tmp]#brew postinstall mysql@5.7
==> Postinstalling mysql@5.7
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.28/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=gert --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.28 --datadir=/usr/local/var/my  Last 15 lines from /Users/gert/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql@5.7/post_install.01.mysqld: 2019-12-09 08:03:39 +0200

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.28/bin/mysqld
--initialize-insecure
--user=gert
--basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.28
--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
--tmpdir=/tmp

2019-12-09T06:03:39.151987Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2019-12-09T06:03:39.154025Z 0 

[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting. 2019-12-09T06:03:39.154074Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Trying to start mysql as root gives error:

> [08:04:41][~/tmp]#sudo /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql.server start
>   Password: Starting MySQL ..... ERROR! The server quit without updating
>   PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).

Banging head against wall for days now trying to follow StackOverflow posts [MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/25683395#25683395), none of which is working ...

My my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#SO posts said to comment out the above ...

pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid  #Checked, this folder + file exists, with write permissions
```

Comment: Are you sure it's completely empty, without even any invisible files? (Note that "." and ".." are *always* present, and shouldn't/can't be removed.)

Comment: Yep, absolutely 100% sure. No hidden files either. Just did it again, same error (data folder not empty)... Fundamental bug here me thinks, either in MySQL or in Brew

Answer (score 0):

Try using a data dir away from the mysql directory i.e if mysql is in /usr/local/mysql, use the data dir as /var/data.

```
root@photon [ /var ]# /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql --datadir=/var/data
2020-02-22T21:42:27.121230Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) initializing of server in progress as process 820
2020-02-22T21:42:35.018238Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```